# Advanced IIS Routing

Tags: iis, routes, arr

I have a situation where there are two versions of the same website live at the same time; only differentiated by sections. As we launch a new section, we route traffic to the newer site and remove access from the old site. Im wondering if Application Request Routing (or similar routing software) can be used to specify url patterns, and forward to a binding (same host) with a specific IP address?